# Sorting in a sql query, disregarding the numbers at the start of the field?

Tags: php, sql, sorting

I need to sort items on a website in a bit of a weird way:

Just say my data is:

```
681A
500AB
300BB
```

i need it to be in this order, so i need it to disregard the number at the start and order by the first letter it encounters.

Is there a way to do this in a sql query? Or will i have to create an array on the page and sort it that way with php?

Thanks in advance if anyone can help out.

Answer (score 1):

A way you can try to do that is to add a substring in your query and use it to sort.

Note that this will work only if you **always** have 3 char to ignore.

`SELECT fieldA, fieldB, SUBSTRING(fieldB,4) as subfieldB FROM myTable order by subsfieldB`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create additional column in your table, storing these abbreviations in the form you'd like to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

If the prefix number is always 3 digits long, then this would be reasonable:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(field1,4) AS shortfield1
FROM table
ORDER BY shortcol
```

see

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr

Answer (score 0):

Take a look how to make a regex replacement on sql or try to use replace function some thing like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT REPLACE([YourCol],'0','') AS COL, *
    FROM [table]
) as T
ORDER BY [COL]
```

- note that regex does not has a great performance

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it could be the best option, because it could be any number length so i just need to take the number off the front, now to sharpen up my regex skills

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table order by substring(NNNN,startposition,endposition) asc
```

Comment: When you are providing an answer, please provide an explanation too. Just code doesn't help people to understand. and btw, I don't think this even answers the question